# React - Module not found: Can't resolve component

Tags: reactjs, docker

I'm trying to deploy a React website using Docker, but when I'm building the docker image I get:

`Module not found: Error: Can't resolve './components/Home' in '/app/src'`

I'm developping the application in a Windows environment but my docker container is hosted on a Linux machine (in Microsoft Azure).

My files are organised like this:

```
 ├ src/
 | ├── index.js
 | ├── App.js
 | └── components/
 |     └─── Home.js
 ├ public/
 ├ Dockerfile
 ├ package.json
 └ yarn.lock
```

My dockerfile:

```
FROM node:18-alpine

WORKDIR /app

COPY package.json /app/package.json
COPY yarn.lock /app/yarn.lock
COPY src /app/src
COPY public /app/public

RUN yarn
RUN yarn run build

RUN yarn global add serve

EXPOSE 3000

CMD ["serve", "-s", "build"]
```

My `App.js` looks like:

```
import "./App.css";
import React, { lazy } from "react";
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Routes, Route, Navigate } from "react-router-dom";

const Home = lazy(() => import("./components/Home"));

const App = () => {
  return (
    <Router>
      <Routes>
        <Route exact path="/home" element={<Home />} />
        <Route path="*" element={<Navigate replace to="/home" />} />
      </Routes>
    </Router>
  );
};

export default App;
```

My `Home.js` looks like:

```
import React from "react";

const Home = () => {
  return (
    <h1>Home Page</h1>
  );
};

export default Home;
```

If I run the website **localy** only using the following terminal commands:

```
yarn && yarn start
```

or

```
yarn && yarn run build
serve -s build
```

I don't run into the error.

If I move my `Home.js` file oustide the `components/` folder (resulting in it being in the same folder as my `App.js` I don't have the error message and the application runs, that would be an ok solution if my website only used the `Home` component but I have multiple files with multiple components and I don't want to just dump them in my `src/` folder.

I already saw a lot of posts with similar errors but the solution is often to just check for caps errors in file path, and I have done that a million times already.

Any help would be appreciated at this point...

Comment: Do you have this issue only for the lazy imports, or all imports?

Comment: I have the issue for all imports.

Answer (score 0):

Changing your file structure for both systems would be a viable option as docker needs a lot of clarification on file paths to create an image.
[here's somewhat the same problem in Linux for a user](https://community.render.com/t/module-not-found/7204/6)

Comment: Thanks for your answer ! The issue you linked seems to be caused by a cassing problems but I checked mine several times already. What do you mean by changing the file structure?

Comment: you need to have a different file structure for the machine where docker is installed and working. try running your project locally on Linux and then push for the docker image. that'll resolve the issue. or install docker on the same machine where your project is because there are different dependencies for different machines.